# How to associate a 4-char OSType / NSFileHFSTypeCode with a particular UTI

Tags: cocoa, macos, file-manipulation, macfuse

I am writing a MacFuse plugin, and would like finder to use the appropriate icons & launch the appropriate app when a file is opened.

It is not possible for me to add an extension to the file, so my only other option in Snow Leopard is the NSFileHFSTypeCode.  I have reviewed all of the codes registered on my machine using http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/ and I can see that some of the codes are associated with UTIs.  For example `'TEXT'` is associated with the uniform type identifier (UTI) `com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-text`.

I would like to be able to associate some of these 4-char codes with other UTIs.  For example `PHPf` to `public.php-script`.  I imagine that there's some kind of framework or command line utility that would allow me to do this, but I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the UTI in your bundle's Info.plist. If it's your own UTI, export it; if it's someone else's, import it.

See [the UTI docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/) for more information.